# Spring Data JPA: Unable to delete child records in OneToOne relationship using ON DELETE CASCADE with foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

I am using Spring Data JPA to map a OneToOne relationship between two entities in my application. The entities are DM and DM_DATA, where each DM record has exactly one corresponding DM_DATA record.

The DM table has a foreign key constraint to the DM_DATA table using the DM_DATA_ID column to map to DMD_DATA_ID (primary key in DM_DATA). The relationship is defined in the JPA entities using a @OneToOne and @JoinColumn annotation on the DM entity and a @OneToOne(mappedBy = "dmData") annotation on the DM_DATA entity.

I have also added the CASCADE option to the @OneToOne annotation in the DM entity to enable cascading delete.

**Parent:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DM")
public class FileDm {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "DM_FILE_ID")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.REMOVE},
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "DMD_DATA_ID", referencedColumnName = "DMD_DATA_ID")
    private DmData dmData;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true) 
    @JoinColumn(name="DM_DCMT_ID", nullable=true)
    private DmType dmType;

        ...
}
```

**Child:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DM_DATA")
public class DmData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "DMD_DATA_ID")
    private long code;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "dmData")
    private FileDm fileDm;

    @Column(name = "DMD_DATA")
    private String data;

        ...
}
```

Also I have written an sql script to change the **DB schemes** and do **migrations**:

```
ALTER TABLE DM ADD COLUMN DM_DATA_ID bigint(20);

CREATE TABLE DM_DATA (
    DMD_DATA_ID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TEMP_DATA_ID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    DMD_DATA longblob,
    PRIMARY KEY (DMD_DATA_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;

INSERT INTO DM_DATA(TEMP_DATA_ID, DMD_DATA)
    (SELECT d.DM_FILE_ID, d.DM_DATA
     FROM DM d
     WHERE d.DM_DATA IS NOT NULL);

UPDATE DM d
    INNER JOIN DM_DATA dd
    ON d.DM_FILE_ID = dd.TEMP_DATA_ID
    SET d.DM_DATA_ID = dd.DMD_DATA_ID;

ALTER TABLE DM_DATA DROP TEMP_DATA_ID;
ALTER TABLE DM DROP DM_DATA;
```

so I end up with these **DB schemes**:

```
DM | CREATE TABLE `DM` (
  `DM_FILE_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DM_DATA_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DM_DCMT_ID` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DM_FILE_ID`),
  KEY `FK_DM_DMTYPE_idx` (`DM_DCMT_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DM_DMTYPE` FOREIGN KEY (`DM_DCMT_ID`) REFERENCES `DMTYPE` (`DCMT_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DM_DATA_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`DM_DATA_ID`) REFERENCES `DM_DATA` (`DMD_DATA_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci |

| DM_DATA | CREATE TABLE `DM_DATA` (
  `DMD_DATA_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DMD_DATA` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DMD_DATA_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci |
```

However, when I delete a DM record either by repository method or by delete statement from db, DM_DATA record **is not removed**.

I have tried to add the foreign key constraint to the DM_DATA table using the DMD_DATA_ID column, but that did not solve the problem. I also tried switching the direction of the foreign key relationship, but that resulted in a different error when inserting a new record.

Is there any way to properly configure the OneToOne relationship in JPA and mirror it in sql script to enable cascading delete of the child entity?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the direction of the relationship:

**Parent:**

```
@OneToOne(
        mappedBy = "fileDm",
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE },
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private DmData dmData;
```

**Child:**

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DMD_FILE_ID")
private FileDm fileDm;
```

And in the sql schema definition and migration script I changed TEMP_DATA_ID  to DMD_FILE_ID and added foreign key constraint

```
CREATE TABLE DM_DATA (
    DMD_DATA_ID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DMD_FILE_ID bigint(20),
    DMD_DATA longblob,
    PRIMARY KEY (DMD_DATA_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;

INSERT INTO DM_DATA(DMD_FILE_ID, DMD_DATA)
    (SELECT d.DM_FILE_ID, d.DM_DATA
     FROM DM d
     WHERE d.DM_DATA IS NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE DM DROP DM_DATA;
ALTER TABLE OH_DM_DATA
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DM_DATA
    FOREIGN KEY (DMD_FILE_ID)
    REFERENCES DM (DM_FILE_ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I still can't figure out why it failed to work the original way.